# Best Azure data centre for serving the western world

Tags: azure

What is the best Microsoft Azure data centre to use for serving Western Europe, North America and Japan?

Stack Overflow is warning me that my question appears to be subjective, so let me make it concrete.  Which data centre will have the best average ping time weighted by the population in these areas?  It seems that the Azure firewall won't let ping through, but I guess that the HTTP connect time is a decent proxy.

(In the long term we may host our site in multiple data centres, but that requires extra hosting costs and extra work, so for now we don't want that.)

Comment: No matter what data center people suggest, be sure you're aware what services are and are not available at that data center. For example, US West does not (last I checked) support SQL Azure. So if you host your app at that data center and later need SQL support, you'll be going across data centers to make that happen (and paying for bandwidth). There is quite a bit of fragmentation with what services are available at each data center. Looking into this will likely narrow your search down significantly for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to serve all of them, you'll need a datacenter in all of those locations. I'd say use these:

- Western Europe: `West Europe` location (Amsterdam, Netherlands)
- North America: Either `US West` (California, where silicons valley is) or `US East` (Virginia, most of the americans live on the east coast)
- Japan: `East Asia` (Hong kong)

There's just no way your site is going to be fast in Japan if you place your software on a server in western Europe (and the other way around).

But IF you decide to choose only 1 location I'd say choose `West Europe` because the western part of Europa has a population of around 420M, the eastern part of the US has a population of  roughly 120M and Japan is around the same number (but it's quite far from the east asia datacenter).

You only have to keep in mind that your site/service will be horribly slow to the rest of the world. So your idea of serving 3 different continents is not going to work.

Comment: To add to Leon's answer, for the problem of site/service slow for rest of the world, you can bring in Azure Traffic Manager to solve that based on Geography Based Routing.

Comment: Take advantage of the Content Delivery Network for serving static content, too. That'll help reduce the overall latency.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted some hard numbers to add to @Leon Cullen's answer so I set up a publicly-accessible blob in three Azure data centres and used [Nimsoft](http://www.nimsoft.com/solutions/nimsoft-monitor.html) to monitor it from many different locations.  The numbers are my rough averages of HTTP connect times, gained by browsing the logs.

Data centre Western US

- Western Europe 170-180ms
- North America <80ms

Data centre Eastern US

- Western Europe 90-110ms
- North America <80ms

Data centre Western Europe

- Western Europe <30ms
- North America 100-150

From this I conclude:

- @Leon Cullen's answer is right.
- Western Europe has fast interconnects.
- The Eastern US data centre is pretty good for keeping western countries below 100ms.
- The atlantic hop costs about 100ms.  (By contrast the hop from Australia to the US costs about 200ms :-(, but we're used to that.  All of Asia is about the same cost.)

Comment: Nice that you've benchmarked this and posted the results. Good luck with your implementation :)

Comment: Nice analysis. For others that don't have access to Nimsoft, I found a useful site that can do the same: https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency
However it only measures from your browser location, so you could set up VM's in the various datacentres and use it from there if you want to test it yourself.
Region to region stats are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/azure-network-latency
Lastly, I understand North Europe is slightly cheaper than West Europe, but it is minimal. and maybe 4ms closer to the USA.